# Merging images from different source folders

Tags: python, image, merge

I have two different folders a and b. The 'a' folder contains images of the format a_i.jpg (where i = 1 to N). The 'b' folder contains images of the format b_i.jpg. I want to merge these images taking a_1 and merging it with b_1, a_2 with b_2, .... a_N with b_N and then store the new image dataset in a different folder that contains 'N' merged images of the same format and n_i.jpg.

NOTE: I made sure that all the images are of the same size.

With this code I'm able to merge singular files, but how do I loop over the entire folders as mentioned above?

```
images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['in.jpg', 'tulips.jpg']]
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

x_offset = 0
for im in images:
  new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
  x_offset += im.size[0]

new_im.save('new2.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below solution is what you are looking for

```
source_folder1 = "a"
source_folder2 = "b"
target_folder = "Image_Merged"
for img_no in range(1,n+1):
    img1 = source_folder1+"_"+str(img_no)+".jpg"
    img2 = source_folder2+"_"+str(img_no)+".jpg"
    
    images = [Image.open(x) for x in [img1, img2]]
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

    total_width = sum(widths)
    max_height = max(heights)

    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))


    x_offset = 0
    for im in images:
      new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
      x_offset += im.size[0]

    new_im.save(target_folder+"/target_folder_"+str(img_no)+".jpg")
```

Comment: Thanks @Palash Jhamb. I tried it but it's throwing a "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/a_1' error". All I did was to add a "/" before the a and b directories since they are located in the path of my work file. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: It can be because of not adding the file extension. I will update the answer. Try now

Comment: Thanks alot @Palash Jhamb. It worked perfectly as I wanted. I'm really grateful for your patience and help! God bless you man!!!

Comment: @BaoLuo if you found my answer useful please upvote the answer and give a tick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

based on @palash-jhamb answer, there are few changes

```
from PIL import Image

source_folder1 = 'a/'
source_folder2 = 'b/'
target_folder = 'Image_Merged/'

n = len(source_folder1)+1

for img_no in range(1,n+1):
    img1 = (source_folder1+str(img_no)+".jpg")
    img2 = (source_folder2+str(img_no)+".jpg")
    
    images = [Image.open(x) for x in [img1, img2]]
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

    total_width = sum(widths)
    max_height = max(heights)

    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))


    x_offset = 0
    for im in images:
      new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
      x_offset += im.size[0]

    new_im.save(target_folder+"/target_folder_"+str(img_no)+".jpg")
```